# image xcassets problems: It change the look of my game

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Hey guys simple question: It is really necessary to transform the images to a 2x and 3x? I did it after i finish the game and now my whole game changed (it looks very small). Now I don't know what to do should I resize the whole game? what can you guys recommend? (im making the game just for iphone)(spritekit)

Comment: How did you transform them? Did you actually make 2 extra sets of assets that are 2x and 3x the size of the originals? If you did that, the perceived "size" wouldn't really change.

Comment: there's an app called prepo, i transformed the original to a 2x and 3x..now my game looks small

Comment: you should not just add the 2x and 3x extension to existing images which are actually for 1x. That causes the images to be displayed as they were for 2x or 3x, meaning that they have a higher resolution. If you just keep the old image and tell the system that it is in fact 2x/3x it will be displayed smaller (1cm on iPhone 6 covers far more pixels than on a iPhone 4). What you have to do is *create* a higher resolution version of the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `Prepo` won't make the deal. Using Photoshop or any other photo editing software, or whatever you used to create your game art, create higher resolution pictures for 2x and 3x. You can achieve that by putting the PPI (Pixels per inch) higher. Then add them to Xcode and it should run without making you game appear smaller, as now the resolution is higher. This should fix your problem.

Hope that helps.